# How do i listen to data posted to webhook in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webhooks

I have setup a webhook, that facebook posts data to. Basically its just a test webhook using https://webhook.site/.

Now how do i reflect this data on my client side (I am using react using create-react-app, but even a generic solution without using create react app will do ), How do i listen to this data, so i can refesh my frontend and show this data on my frontend.

Comment: [Webhooks](https://youtu.be/rUaDIH5ZXB8) is event based communication between 2 servers, you are probably looking for web socket. A client can open a socket to a server and on certain events the server can send messages to clients.

Answer (score 3):

You need a server that can listen to incoming requests. From this server you could establish a websocket connection to your frontend to reflect these changes in real time.

Some resources:

- [Hello World Express (Node.js)](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)
- [Get Started with socket.io (Websocket wrapper)](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

Comment: thanks will check and accept